# Unbiased estimator of an integral raised to a power

Tags: monte-carlo, numerical-integration

I'd like to estimate an integral of the following form using Monte Carlo method:

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} g(t) \left[ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(t, u) du \right] ^\gamma dt$$

In case of $\gamma$ being a positive integer (say, $2$) I can rewrite it as follows:

$$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} g(t) f(t, u_1) f(t, u_2) du_1 du_2 dt$$

That is, I can simply take two independent unbiased estimates of the inner integral and multiply them. My question is: could something similar be done in case of fractional $\gamma$?

Comment: There are myriad ways to estimate integrals.  How do you want to do it?  Using what information, with what computing limitations, to what accuracy?

Comment: @whuber It's Monte Carlo integration in the context of real-time computer graphics. Usually there's budget for 1-4 samples per frame only, but for most pixels you can average results from previous frames (that's why I want an unbiased estimate).

Comment: But Monte-Carlo integration of what, exactly?  There are two distinct integrals here.  If we suppose you can readily evaluate the inner integral, this is a generic MC problem.  Or maybe you want to approximate the inner integral, take its power, and then *compute* the outer integral directly?  You need to edit this post to provide enough context for us to find a reliable interpretation of what you're trying to ask.

Comment: @whuber I can compute neither of the integrals directly. I'm trying to approximate both of them using single MC method, rather than two nested ones. Does it make sense?

Comment: According to https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.14119 the more general problem is called "nested integration" and the thing I'm trying to avoid is called "double-loop Monte Carlo estimator".

Comment: Please be aware there are many, many more methods of estimating integrals than MC methods!  You should make your intentions more specific by editing the post to indicate this.

Comment: @whuber I'd love to improve my question, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. I already use a deterministic method, which looks pretty good but is inflexible meaning it demands $f$ and $g$ to be of specific form and also suffers from discretisation artefacts. I don't find this relevant to the topic of this site though. Could you please give some examples of the other methods you have in mind? I thought unbiased MC is the only method that would work for any $f$ and $g$ and is capable of converging to the true value via aggregation of independent runs.

Comment: There is an entire branch of mathematics devoted to estimating integrals.  Indeed, much of physics is involved in that too.  For instance, Feynman diagrams are a method to estimate otherwise intractable integrals.  Thus, at a minimum, your question needs to specify you reject all such approaches and require MC methods.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a [Bernoulli factory](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernoulli.html#1_1__x___y____lambda) for solving this problem, namely producing unbiased estimates of the powered inner integral. Let us assume

1. $0<\gamma<1$,
2. $0<\varrho=\int f(t,x)\,\text dx<1$ (removing the dependence on $t$ to simplify notations).

Simulating a [Bernoulli variate](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernoulli.html#1_1__x___y____lambda) with probability **and expectation** $\varrho^{\gamma}$ can then be achieved by the following scheme, provided by Peter Occil (and attributed to [Mendo, 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.08923)):

```
 Repeat the following process, until this algorithm returns a value x:
 i. Set k=1
 ii. Generate a Bernoulli B(ϱ) variate z; if z=1, return x=1
 iii. Else, with probability γ/k, return x=0
 iv. Else, set k=k+1 and return to ii.
```

An R rendering of the above

```
bf<-function(p=.5,g=1,x=-1){
while(x<0){
 F=F+1
 x=ifelse(rbinom(1,1,p),
   1,x+rbinom(1,1,g/F))}
x}
```

Each time $\varrho$ is called, it can furthermore be replaced with an unbiased and independent estimator.

Comment: Thanks for Bernoulli factories! They look promising.